# Exception with Crystal Reports on IIS 6

Tags: exception, iis, crystal-reports, windows-server-2003

Hi i encountered a problem on my production environement with Crystal Reports 13. My OS is Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6.
I explain:
Since many month, my production environement worked with Crystal Reports 10 but 1 month ago i install Crystal Reports 13. I precise the 2 version Cohabite and i change in the web.config versions of assembly. Since, i got 2 problems, the first is resolved, i increase the printjoblimit to 150. The other problem who was not resolved is an exception :

```
    Une erreur interne a été détectée. Veuillez nous excuser pour le désagrément.
L'appel à la fonction Suiv_Click a levé l'exception suivante : 
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException: Chemin d'accès au fichier de rapport non valide. à 
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.EngineExceptionUtils.DoThrowException(String
message, EngineExceptionErrorID id) à CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ExceptionThrower.ThrowEngineException(String 
messageID, EngineExceptionErrorID id) à 
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename,
 OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob) à 
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.EnsureLoadReport() à 
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSourceInternal(Object val, 
Type type) à CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(DataSet 
dataSet) à WebOvins_DocumentCirculationv3.CreerEtat_DocCirculation(dsDocCirculation ds) 
dans d:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Synel\WOC\WOC\DocumentCirculationv3.aspx.cs:ligne 1182 à 
WebOvins_DocumentCirculationv3.Suiv_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) dans 
d:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Synel\WOC\WOC\DocumentCirculationv3.aspx.cs:ligne 1009
```

The exception occur beetween 12 or 16 o'clock when i print a report. Before no problem. I supposed is a problem of load. In the night something was flush?

Do you have an idea?

Sorry for my english.

Thanks

Comment: Search for "LoadSaveReportException" on google

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code.

```
    private void CreerEtat_DocCirculation(dsDocCirculation ds)
    {
        //try
        //{
            // Variables utilisées pour la suppression dans le fichier aspx
            objname = this.Session.SessionID;
            objtype = "dir";

            ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();

            //if (Master.ElevageCours.TypeAdhesion != eTypeAdhesion.V1 && !Master.ElevageCours.SansInventaire)
            if (false)
            {
                rd.Load(this.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "WOC\\Editions\\DocCirculation.rpt");
            }
            else
            {
                rd.Load(this.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "WOC\\Editions\\DocCirculationv3.rpt");
            }

            rd.SetDataSource(new dsDocCirculation());

            // Remplissage des divers paramètres de l'édition
            rd.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["AFFANI"].Text = "'0'"; // Suppression de la section liste des animaux

            //if (Master.ElevageCours.TypeAdhesion != eTypeAdhesion.V1 && !Master.ElevageCours.SansInventaire)
            if (false)
            {
                if (vuesDocumentCirculation.GetActiveView().Equals(vueChargement))
                {
                    EditionDocCirculation.AffectationParametres(rd,
                                                                (DocCirculation)Session[sSession.DocumentCirculation],
                                                                Master.ElevageCours,
                                                                0,//txtNbOvinsCharge.Text == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtNbOvinsCharge.Text),
                                                                0,//txtNbCaprinsCharge.Text == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtNbCaprinsCharge.Text),
                                                                0,
                                                                BaseWOC,
                                                                Master.UtilisateurCours.EnDemo ? Coord_ARSOE : null,
                                                                true);
                }
                else
                {
                    EditionDocCirculation.AffectationParametres(rd,
                                                                (DocCirculation)Session[sSession.DocumentCirculation],
                                                                Master.ElevageCours,
                                                                0,//txtNbOvinsDecharge.Text == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtNbOvinsDecharge.Text),
                                                                0,//txtNbCaprinsDecharge.Text == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtNbCaprinsDecharge.Text),
                                                                txtNbMortsDecharge.Text == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtNbMortsDecharge.Text),
                                                                BaseWOC,
                                                                Master.UtilisateurCours.EnDemo ? Coord_ARSOE : null,
                                                                false);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (vuesDocumentCirculation.GetActiveView().Equals(vueChargement))
                {
                    EditionDocCirculation.AffectationParametresV3(rd,
                                                                (DocCirculation)Session[sSession.DocumentCirculation],
                                                                Master.ElevageCours,
                                                                txtNbAgneauxOvinsCharge.Text == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtNbAgneauxOvinsCharge.Text),
                                                                txtNbReproducteursOvinsCharge.Text == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtNbReproducteursOvinsCharge.Text),
                                                                txtNbAgneauxCaprinsCharge.Text == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtNbAgneauxCaprinsCharge.Text),
                                                                txtNbReproducteursCaprinsCharge.Text == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtNbReproducteursCaprinsCharge.Text),
                                                                0,
                                                                BaseWOC,
                                                                Master.UtilisateurCours.EnDemo ? Coord_ARSOE : null,
                                                                true);
                }
                else
                {
                    EditionDocCirculation.AffectationParametresV3(rd,
                                                                (DocCirculation)Session[sSession.DocumentCirculation],
                                                                Master.ElevageCours,
                                                                txtNbAgneauxOvinsDecharge.Text == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtNbAgneauxOvinsDecharge.Text),
                                                                txtNbReproducteursOvinsDecharge.Text == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtNbReproducteursOvinsDecharge.Text),
                                                                txtNbAgneauxCaprinsDecharge.Text == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtNbAgneauxCaprinsDecharge.Text),
                                                                txtNbReproducteursCaprinsDecharge.Text == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtNbReproducteursCaprinsDecharge.Text),
                                                                txtNbMortsDecharge.Text == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtNbMortsDecharge.Text),
                                                                BaseWOC,
                                                                Master.UtilisateurCours.EnDemo ? Coord_ARSOE : null,
                                                                false);
                }
            }


            if (ds.dtListeBoucles.Count == 0)
                rd.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["AFFBOUCLES"].Text = "'0'";
            else
            {
                // Affichage de la liste des boucles
                rd.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["AFFBOUCLES"].Text = "'1'";
                rd.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(ds);
                rd.Subreports[1].SetDataSource(ds);
            }

            // Affichage de l'aperçu
            rd.Export(Editions.OptionsImpression(this.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Editions\\" + objname + "\\DocCirculation.pdf"));
        //}
        //catch (Exception e)
        //{
        //    String str = string.Empty;
        //    str = "L'appel à la fonction CreerEtat_DocCirculation a levé l'exception suivante : " + e.ToString();
        //    Exception ex = new Exception(str);
        //    Session["LastError"] = ex;
        //    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "ErrApplication", "window.open('/WOC/WOC/PopUp/ErreurInterne.aspx','Params','resizable=no,width=400,height=270');", true);
        //}

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing the code we cannot determine the reason for this exception. with this exception , a simple idea is that the location of the report too be created is not exist and unavailable or dont have permission

Comment: I see in my code i don't "close" and "dispose" my ReportDocument. The thing who's strange is the exception was shown after some hours of use.

Comment: If you can, paste the code here which rises the exception, that would definitely help to debug or find the error